# Multiple domains mapped to separate index pages with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have many domains pointing at a hosting folder and I'd like to serve up different pages for the root depending upon the domain name.

Like:

```
http://domainone.com --> serves up one.html as index page
http://domaintwo.com --> serves up two.html as index page
```

I'd like to serve up the different pages per domain, BUT I don't want to redirect them.  Pretty much, I'd like to route or map to these files with .htaccess.

I've got this, but it does a redirect and shows the file name.  Anyway to map it instead?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.){0,1}domain(.+)(\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://domain%2\.com/%2.html [L]
```

---

### ANSWER:

Answer from anubhava, explanation from Panama Jack. Thanks!
Generalized cause my html file's name is part of the url. :)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.){0,1}domain(.+)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %2.html [L]
```

Comment: If you use the domain name it will perform an external redirect. So you have to just rewrite to the `file` itself or use the `[P]` flag to proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ one.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domaintwo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ two.html [L]
```

Comment: Awesome! You're the .htaccess master!

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.){0,1}domain(.+)\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?$ %2.html [L]